# Error in executing JAX-RPC

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rpc

Help me on this exception , Occurs during calling wcf webservice
Log by netbeans

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:107)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy32.logon(Unknown Source)
    at newtestclient.NewTestClient.main(NewTestClient.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.<clinit>(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:533)
    ... 5 more
```

Java Result: 1

Answer (score 0):

The exception says :

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext`.

It's a common error that appears when there is a conflict between libraries and its dependencies. You should try to execute your code in a test project with only the libraries from JAX-RPC, and then add one by one the rest of your app libraries.

**Also, you should check your server libraries to discard any kind of conflict for having the same library (or its dependencies) in your app and in your server with different versions.**